# Why is $balance not equal to 0.01 in if statement when the $balance is 0.01 above?

Tags: php

I have a problem with an `if` statement. The program doesn't go inside the `if` when it seems that the condition is true.

I tried to change the operator `>=` to `==` but it still doesn't work. It works with `<=` but I need `>=` and I also can't explain to myself why it's not working.

```
<?php

$balance = 0.03;      // input 0.03 

if($balance >= 0.02)
{
    $returned = ((floor($balance / 0.02)) * 0.02); // 0.02
    $balance = $balance - $returned;               // 0.03 - 0.02 = 0.01 left
}

echo var_dump($balance) . PHP_EOL;

if($balance >= 0.01)                // why doesnt go in ?
{
    echo "Print Smt ....";
}
```

Why is the second `if` not true? Isn't 0.01 equal to 0.01?

Comment: When working with currency, use bcmath https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Comment: on line 13 $balance is actually `0.0099999999999999984734433411404097569175064563751220703125`  which is less than 0.01, but when var_dump wants to show it, var_dump truncates it to something more readable: 0.01 - use `var_dump(number_format($balance,100))` to see the full number.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$balance` is reassigned value `-1.47` which is less than `0.01`.

Comment: actually, by line 13 it has the value `0.0099999999999999984734433411404097569175064563751220703125` - use `var_dump(number_format($number,100));` to see the full number